# Sending a command using ssh with libssh2 lib

Tags: c, libssh2

I try to use libssh2 to send a command over ssh, but cannot receive the expected response.

It connects well wwith my raspberry pi.

function to send a command:

```
char * s7c_hardware::sendCmd(char * cmd, bool out)
{
        if (!(channel = libssh2_channel_open_session(session))) return "-1";
        libssh2_channel_setenv(channel, "FOO", "bar");
        if (libssh2_channel_request_pty(channel, "vanilla")) return "-2";
        if (libssh2_channel_shell(channel)) return "-3";
        int rc;
        while ((rc = libssh2_channel_exec(channel, cmd)) ==
            LIBSSH2_ERROR_EAGAIN)
        {
            waitsocket(sock, session);
        }
        char * output = "";
        if (out)
        {
            do
            {
                char buffer[99999];
                rc = libssh2_channel_read(channel, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
                if (rc > 0)
                {
                    fprintf(stderr, "We read:\n");
                    for (int i = 0; i < rc; ++i)
                        fputc(buffer[i], stderr);
                    fprintf(stderr, "\n");
                }
                else {
                    if (rc != LIBSSH2_ERROR_EAGAIN)
                        fprintf(stderr, "libssh2_channel_read returned %d\n", rc);
                }
            } while (rc > 0);
        }
        libssh2_channel_free(channel);
        channel = NULL;
        return output;
}
```

Where `cmd` is the command and `out` is if wants output or not.

And if I try to send "uptime" and receive the up time, I receive this instead:

```
We read:

The programs included with the Debian GNU/Linux system are free software;
the exact distribution terms for each program are described in the
individual files in /usr/share/doc/*/copyright.

Debian GNU/Linux comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, to the extent
permitted by applicable law.
Last login: Sat Jul  1 10:27:51 2017 from desktop-ca160hm.local

We read:
pi@rasp:~$
```

Comment: `cmd = cmd + '\n';` C strings do not work this way. Try to print your `cmd` to console before sending it.

Comment: Also, i'm removing `C++` tag in favour of `C`.

Comment: @iehrlich Ok, That's for my c++ aplication, but that part is only C, you are right. The `cmd = cmd + '\n'` is because my old lib I used, but this one don't need it.

Comment: @iehrlich Code fixed!

Comment: @iehrlich The command is correct before sending it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe requesting a shell and requesting a single command's execution are mutually exclusive. If you want to run a command, get its output, and end the channel (not necessarily the session), you should run `libssh2_channel_exec` and *not* run `libssh2_channel_shell`.